# Is there a performance hit on development-enabled iOS devices?

Tags: iphone, ios

Here's my situation:

I've got a personal iPhone 4 that I use day-to-day, and I was thinking of using it for development.

If I do enable my iPhone for development, will there be any noticeable difference with regards to the performance of the device?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not significantly. If there's any diagnostic information that needs to be collected, it's crash logs, which are already generated on a regular basis by all devices from day 1. When you enable your device for development, Xcode just collects information about it once, presumably to know how to decide how to work with it as you build and test your apps.

You may have debug versions of your apps on your iPhone, but I seriously doubt they will affect OS performance. Even if they do stuff that causes them to slow down it should only happen while their debuggers are running.

Anyway, when it comes to using your personal device for development, I am sure there are other, more important concerns than performance.

Anecdotally, my white iPhone 4 disagrees that it was "violated" in any way by Xcode. In fact it seems pleased to work with it. But that could be just because it knows a developer owns it, so it gets itself in the testing mood.

Comment: On a debug version of an app, won't it do an override of `NSLog` to output to a logfile? You don't think that could do something wrt performance?

Comment: How do you think it's possible to look in the Console of a certain app in Organizer? Yeah, that's gotta come from somewhere.

Comment: @Jacob: Fair enough, but I don't think it's enough I/O to slow your entire device down noticeably.

Comment: Definitely agree, no noticeable performance hit on my iPhone 4 or iPad 2. Even my original iPhone was just as fast when I had it set up for development.

Answer (score 0):

I think the performance difference is minimal. All iOS devices in our house are enabled for debugging (because I like to try out my apps on all sorts of devices) and I haven't been able to tell the difference.

But it might be something personal, something you would have to try for yourself. Just make sure you make a backup of your device, before enabling. If you think it slows down your device to much, just restore to the backup.